# Convexity adjustment--Assume sport and futures rates move together?

Tags: interest-rates, convexity

A cash flow argument I typically see for why a convexity adjustment is necessary is the following (taken loosely from Hull 9/e, p. 143):

> Say I am short an interest rate futures contract (e.g. Eurodollars).
>   If the futures rate (the rate referenced in the contract) rises, then
>   I am credited funds in my margin account and am able to invest these
>   proceeds at a higher rate.  Conversely, if the futures rate falls,
>   then I have a loss in my margin account and must finance this loss but
>   at a lower rate.

Therefore the market will set the futures rate higher since the long side of this transaction will experience the opposite effect of investing/financing the daily settlements (finance at higher rates, invest at lower rates).

What is not clear to me is that the **spot rate** at which I am able to invest/borrow the balance of my margin account changes in the same direction as the **futures rate**.  The type of argument given above seems to implicitly assume the two rates always move in the same direction--is this correct?  If so, does this assumption always hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right.  The convexity adjustment is proportional to the correlation between the spot rate (actually , the rate from today to the expiration of the futures) and the futures rate.  In practice the correlation is nearly always positive, although not always close to 100%.  Many simplified explanations ignore this effect.